# Fixed cells width and height in Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

In Excel 2003, I want all the cells have width and height fixed to 2cm by 2cm; How can this be done?

Comment: http://www.excelhowto.com/how-to-set-column-width-in-cm-at-once/ but also, you'll need to change your units to CM assuming they're not already https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Change-the-column-width-and-row-height-72f5e3cc-994d-43e8-ae58-9774a0905f46

Comment: my question is about Excel 2003. These sites do not address this version which does not accept changing measures to cm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple macro,

```
Sub Macro1()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 10.75
    Selection.RowHeight = 27
End Sub
```

Just change the height and width to suit your needs.

Comment: Are the numbers always expressed in inches? Or will the macro adhere to the specified measurement unit?

Comment: Is the value expressed in pixels then?

Comment: You can specify a row height of 0 (zero) to 409. This value represents the height measurement in points (1 point equals approximately 1/72 inch or 0.035 cm). The default row height is 12.75 points (approximately 1/6 inch or 0.4 cm). If a row has a height of 0 (zero), the row is hidden. taken from MS website